# Firebase JS - Permanent offline storage

Tags: javascript, firebase

I'm developing an app using Angular 2, Electron and Firebase. The app is primarily an offline app with the option to sync when online. The problem is, at the moment, Firebase doesn't support permanent storage on the browser. I thought of using PouchDB when offline and syncing it to Firebase when connected. But, I feel like it's going to need too much effort to make the data consistent across the two databases. So, are there any better options for permanent offline storage for a Firebase app? An example would be really awesome too.

Comment: Did you have any luck with this? I've been looking for the same info. This js project might help, it was built for a phonegap app. https://github.com/yeldarby/offline-firebase

Comment: Pouchdb is the best way I found so far. Pouchdb sits between the app and firebase, everything is stored locally on pouchdb and firebase checks if there's data that's not been synced and it syncs it. Not very elegant, but it works.

Comment: @MinION, where can I find PouchDB-Firebase integration tutorial or sample?

Comment: I wasn't able to find examples other than the ones provided here. I ended up implementing the app using PouchDB and MongoDB

Answer (score 0):

## [AngularFire2Offline](https://github.com/adriancarriger/angularfire2-offline)

I was in the same situation and created a library that caches read-only [AngularFire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2) data for offline use. It will use localstorage if the page is loaded offline, and it will use Firebase data when available.

### Demos

- [`Angular 2+ Demo`](https://angularfire2-offline.firebaseapp.com/) -- [tutorial](https://github.com/adriancarriger/angularfire2-offline/blob/master/examples/angular-cli/README.md)
- [`Ionic 2+ Demo`](https://ionic-pwa-ad85b.firebaseapp.com) -- [tutorial](https://github.com/adriancarriger/angularfire2-offline/blob/master/examples/ionic/README.md)

## Basic Usage

### 1. Install

```
npm install angularfire2-offline angularfire2 firebase --save
```

### 2. Component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {
  AngularFireOffline,
  ListObservable,
  ObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2-offline';

@Component({
  selector: 'project-name-app',
  template: `
  <h1>{{ (info | async)?.name }}</h1>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of items | async">
      {{ item?.name }}
    </li>
  </ul>
  `
})
export class MyApp {
  info: ObjectObservable<any>;
  items: ListObservable<any[]>;
  constructor(afo: AngularFireOffline) {
    this.info = afo.database.object('/info');
    this.items = afo.database.list('/items');
  }
}
```

- Methods mirror AngularFire2 database read methods for [`object`](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/2-retrieving-data-as-objects.md#retrieve-data) and [`list`](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/3-retrieving-data-as-lists.md#retrieve-data).
- [Querying lists](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/4-querying-lists.md) is supported

### 3. Module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFireOfflineModule } from 'angularfire2-offline';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

// Must export the config
export const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: '<your-key>',
  authDomain: '<your-project-authdomain>',
  databaseURL: '<your-database-URL>',
  storageBucket: '<your-storage-bucket>'
};

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
    AngularFireOfflineModule.forRoot(),
    BrowserModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```